# Interprocess Communication in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that two threads *in the same process* can communicate with `wait` and `notify`.
How can two threads from different processes communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0):

The taskmanager manages the tasks by spawing multiple user threads from the main thread. The main thread  is always created by default. The user threads 1-3 are run sequentially, i.e. thread-2 starts only after    thread-1  completes, and so on. The user threads 4-6 start and  executes  concurrently.

[image]

```
  public class TaskManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       RunnableTask task = new RunnableTask();

       //threads 1-3 are run sequentially
   Thread thread1 = new Thread(task, "Thread-1");
   Thread thread2 = new Thread(task, "Thread-2");
   Thread thread3 = new Thread(task, "Thread-3");

   thread1.start(); //invokes run() on RunnableTask
   thread1.join();  // main thread blocks (for 10 seconds)
   thread2.start(); //invokes run() on RunnableTask
   thread2.join();  // main thread blocks (for 10 seconds)
   thread3.start(); //invokes run() on RunnableTask
   thread3.join();  // main thread blocks (for 10 seconds)

   Thread thread4 = new Thread(task, "Thread-4");
   Thread thread5 = new Thread(task, "Thread-5");
   Thread thread6 = new Thread(task, "Thread-6");

       thread4.start(); //invokes run() on RunnableTask
       thread5.start(); //invokes run() on RunnableTask
       thread6.start(); //invokes run() on RunnableTask
   }
 }
```

Notice the times of the output. There is a 10 second difference bewteen threads 1-3. But Threads 4-6   started pretty much the same time.

> ```
>  Thread-1 at Fri Mar 02 16:59:22 EST 2012
>  Thread-2 at Fri Mar 02 16:59:32 EST 2012
>  Thread-3 at Fri Mar 02 16:59:42 EST 2012
>  Thread-4 at Fri Mar 02 16:59:47 EST 2012
>  Thread-6 at Fri Mar 02 16:59:47 EST 2012
>  Thread-5 at Fri Mar 02 16:59:47 EST 2012
> ```

Comment: This is a very nice answer, but i'm afraid that op is asking completly another question: he is asking about communication *between* processes, you show difference between serial and parallel threading in a single process.